# Add 2nd Y Axis Caption, Mark line + Add line Caption

Tags: android, androidplot

I got the following Problem,

I would like to :

- add a second Axis Caption to my Android Plot on the right side
- same Labels like right.(maybe)
- mark a line with a color and some text
- the violet line should always be in front the yellow one

Is there any way to do this?

Because a picture says more than thousands of words.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a built in second axis caption, but since they're just instances of `TextLabelWidget` its pretty easy to add your own.  Here's an example that adds a label to the `SimpleXYPlotActivity` example

```
    TextLabelWidget textLabelWidget = new TextLabelWidget(
            plot.getLayoutManager(),
            "some text",
            null,  // TextLabelWidget instances "pack" to wrap the actual text size
            TextOrientation.VERTICAL_ASCENDING);

    textLabelWidget.getLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
    textLabelWidget.getLabelPaint().setTextSize(PixelUtils.dpToPix(24));

    plot.getLayoutManager().add(textLabelWidget);
    textLabelWidget.position(
            // add a right margin of 4dp:
            PixelUtils.dpToPix(4), HorizontalPositioning.ABSOLUTE_FROM_RIGHT,

            // center the text with the plot space vertically:
            0, VerticalPositioning.ABSOLUTE_FROM_CENTER,

            // use the middle of the right edge of the text widget as the anchor:
            Anchor.RIGHT_MIDDLE);
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Is there any possibility to add Labels to the 2nd Axis too?

Comment: sorry didnt notice there were multiple questions in here. Probably better to edit this question and create separate questions for the others, per SOF's rules.  In any case, you can show labels for as many or as few edges as you like in the xml like this: `ap:lineLabels="left|bottom|top|right"`

Comment: Ok, I will remember it for the next time

Comment: Can I set ap:lineLabels via methodecall too?

Comment: You can: `plot.getGraph().setLineLabelEdges(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM, XYGraphWidget.Edge.RIGHT);`